# Form with 3 dropdown menus

Tags: php, javascript, html, opencart

I have a form with three different dropdown menus, it looks like this:

```
 <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="/search.php" method="get">
  <select style="width:55px;" name="filter_name">
  <option> </option>
  <option>R13</option>
  <option>R14</option>
  <option>R15</option>
  <option>R16</option>
  <option>R17</option>
</select></td></tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">Plotis:</td><td colspan="2"><select style="width:55px;" name="">
  <option> </option>
  <option>165</option>
  <option>175</option>
  <option>185</option>
  <option>195</option>
  <option>205</option>
  <option>215</option>
  <option>225</option>
</select></td></tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">Auk&#353;tis:</td><td colspan="2"><select style="width:55px;" name="">
  <option> </option>
  <option>75</option>
  <option>70</option>
  <option>65</option>
  <option>60</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>45</option>
</select></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<INPUT style="width:80px; height:25px; font-size:14px; font-weight:600; cursor:pointer;" TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Ie&#353;koti">
</FORM>
```

Basically, I need to send all 3 Options into next page but joined into one variable..
For example: If I chose

```
<option>165</option>+<option>70</option>+<option>R13</option>
```

it should be sent to index.php like this: `filter_name=165/70/R13`

and also, how to send all this not to index.php only, but to

```
index.php?route=product/search&FILTER_NAME
```

Changing `ACTION="/index.php"` to `ACTION="/index.php?route=product/search"` was not working.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just make the target page accept the distinct form fields, and build the `filter_name` in your PHP code?

Comment: Aside: numeric Unicode escapes in HTML are an abomination, you should consider figuring out the charset settings in PHP / your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. But, you have several errors in your HTML that you should check. You have a nested table within your form.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['send'])) {
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <select style="width:55px;" name="select_one">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="R13">R13</option>
        <option value="R14">R14</option>
        <option value="R15">R15</option>
        <option value="R16">R16</option>
        <option value="R17">R17</option>
    </select>

    <select style="width:55px;" name="select_two">
        <option></option>
        <option value="165">165</option>
        <option value="175">175</option>
        <option value="185">185</option>
        <option value="195">195</option>
        <option value="205">205</option>
        <option value="215">215</option>
        <option value="225">225</option>
    </select>

    <select style="width:55px;" name="select_three">
        <option></option>
        <option value="75">75</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="65">65</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="55">55</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
    </select>

    <input style="width:80px; height:25px; font-size:14px; font-weight:600; cursor:pointer;" type="submit" value="send" value="Ie&#353;koti" />
</form>
<?php
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php?route=product/search&filter_name='.$_POST['select_two'].'/'.$_POST['select_three'].'/'.$_POST['select_one']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like something close to what I need, but after clicking send, Im being redirected to maindomainname.com/index.php?select_one=R17&select_two=175&select_three=60
Btw, I have some php/html code abeve this one, If that changes anything

Comment: UPDATE: I've removed all table errors, and posted exact code you gave me, now after hitting Send, im being redirected to maindomainname.com/index.php?route=common/home with no results. Maybe i should change POST to GET instead?

Comment: I've changed !isset($_POST['send']) to !isset($_POST['select_one']) and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in the invalid markup. You are using table layout, and form is split between cells. That is not  valid, so may be browser renders your layout in an unexpected way.

You can expect this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <form>
        <input>
</td>
<td>
        <input>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

But browser can render your markup as this (2 forms):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <form>
        <input>
    </form>
</td>
<td>
    <form>
        <input>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

So when you submit your form not all data are sent, cause only first form is submitted

Comment: I've removed all table markups at all, and posted code as it is in OptimusCrime answer, the problem is, after clicking Post, im being redirected to maindomainname.com (aka nothing happens) And i want to be redirected to maindomainname.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=JOINED SELECTED OPTIONS

Comment: Is it valid to use multiple method-attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Join the 3 filter options in php into a variable.

```
$options = $_POST['f1'] . '/' . $_POST['f2'] . '/' . $_POST['f3'];
```

It will be less confusing IMO.